# Lazy properties with initializers

Tags: ios, properties, lazy-loading, swift

I am trying to use the `@lazy` attribute to load a property on demand, but I need to pass a member variable into the lazy-loaded instance's initializer.

Here's the example

```
class Worker
{
  init(AnyObject context) { ... }
}

class Hive
{
  let context : AnyObject

  init(AnyObject context)
  {
    self.context = context
  }

  @lazy var worker = Worker(self.context)   // This does not work
}
```

Is there no way to inject member variables into lazy loaded properties?

Here is my rather annoying workaround:

```
class Hive
{
  // initializer and context constant elided

  let lazy = Lazy()

  class Lazy
  {
    var worker : Worker? = nil
    var token : dispatch_once_t = 0
  }

  var worker : Worker
  {
    get
    {
      dispatch_once(&lazy.token) { self.lazy.worker = Worker(self.context) }
      return lazy.worker!
    }
  }
}
```

Please tell me there is a better way to accomplish this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code compiles for me (your code must've been typed up outside of XCode because the syntax is off)

```
class Worker
{
    init(context : AnyObject) {  }
}

class Hive
{
    var context : AnyObject

    init(context : AnyObject)
    {
        self.context = context
    }

    @lazy var worker : Worker = {
        let instance = Worker(context: self.context)
        return instance;
    }()
}
```

It also works without the closure:

```
    @lazy var worker : Worker = Worker(context: self.context)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've edited my workaround code to be more accurate but I appreciate your solution far more!

Comment: @SiLo No problem! And yes, the `@lazy` should be the recommended way for this :]